# Proof Fibonacci Matrix Proprety by Induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, fibonacci-numbers

**Statement: Proof by induction for all $n\geq 1$**

$$\begin{pmatrix}F_n\\F_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm know the induction steps but i keep having troubles with the use of induction in matrices.
Im verified for n=1 and assumed n=k. But can't proced after assume that work for k+1.

I'm stuck in k+1 step.

$$\begin{pmatrix}F_{k+1}\\F_{k+2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

I tried too

$$\begin{pmatrix}F_k+F_{k-1}\\F_{k+1}+F_k\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

but idk how to procede

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: I edit my question to show what i tried and what i'm stucked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because
$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}b\\a+b\end{pmatrix}
$.

(added later)

Therefore,
and this is the induction step,

$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}F_n\\F_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}\\F_n+F_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}\\F_{n+2}\end{pmatrix}
$.

This needs to be combined with

$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^n
=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}
$.

Comment: I didn't get the idea. That's basically what I'm trying to demonstrate, isn't it?

Comment: No. This is a matrix multiplication identity. It allows you to carry the induction step through.

Comment: I think i get the idea. Thanks